How to create a Signer for CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts
I am trying to create an object compatible with metaplex's CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts to be used in createMetadataAccountV3 function. The CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts has below type in Metaplex
export type CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts = {
    /** Metadata key (pda of ['metadata', program id, mint id]) */
    metadata?: PublicKey | Pda;
    /** Mint of token asset */
    mint: PublicKey | Pda;
    /** Mint authority */
    mintAuthority: Signer;
    /** payer */
    payer?: Signer;
    /** update authority info */
    updateAuthority?: PublicKey | Pda | Signer;
    /** System program */
    systemProgram?: PublicKey | Pda;
    /** Rent info */
    rent?: PublicKey | Pda;
};

The mintAuthority expects a Signer interface type which is defined below:
export interface Signer {
    /** The public key of the Signer. */
    readonly publicKey: PublicKey;
    /** Signs the given message. */
    readonly signMessage: (message: Uint8Array) => Promise<Uint8Array>;
    /** Signs the given transaction. */
    readonly signTransaction: (transaction: Transaction) => Promise<Transaction>;
    /** Signs all the given transactions at once. */
    readonly signAllTransactions: (transactions: Transaction[]) => Promise<Transaction[]>;
}

Now, below is my code how I tried to build the data that can be used in createMetadataAccountV3 function
const MY_TOKEN_METADATA: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs = {
    data: {
        name: "Testing",
        symbol: "TST",
        uri: "https://arweave.net/v2PSXJy95LrpkcFytCLw7BCZw0lSNgbfM53VyfImExx",
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
        collection: null,
        creators: [
            {address: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(userWallet.publicKey), verified: true, share: 100}
        ],
        uses: null
    },
    isMutable: false,
    collectionDetails: null
}

const signer = {
        publicKey: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(userWallet.publicKey),
        signMessage: null,
        signTransaction: null,
        signAllTransactions: null
    }
    const accounts: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts = {
        metadata: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(metadataPDA),
        mint: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(metadataPDA), 
        payer: signer,
        mintAuthority: signer,
        updateAuthority: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(userWallet.publicKey)
    }


But in
payer: signer,
mintAuthority: signer
I am getting below error:
Type '{ publicKey: PublicKey; signMessage: null; signTransaction: null; signAllTransactions: null; }' is not assignable to type 'Signer'.
Types of property 'signMessage' are incompatible.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type '(message: Uint8Array) => Promise<Uint8Array>'.


How can I create the Signer correctly?
Below is the whole code
import { Transaction, SystemProgram, Keypair, Connection, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { MINT_SIZE, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, createInitializeMintInstruction, getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint, getAssociatedTokenAddress, createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction, createMintToInstruction } from '@solana/spl-token';
import { DataV2, createMetadataAccountV3, CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts, CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata';
import { bundlrStorage, keypairIdentity, Metaplex, UploadMetadataInput } from '@metaplex-foundation/js';
import secret from './guideSecret.json';
import { createUmi } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults';
import { fromWeb3JsPublicKey, toWeb3JsPublicKey } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-web3js-adapters'

const endpoint = 'https://warmhearted-hardworking-county.solana-devnet.quiknode.pro/cb4264034a8b3997510f99f8f2006389a4b57754/'; //Replace with your RPC Endpoint
const solanaConnection = new Connection(endpoint);
const userWallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(secret));

const MINT_CONFIG = {
    numDecimals: 6,
    numberTokens: 1337
}

const MY_TOKEN_METADATA: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs = {
    data: {
        name: "Testing",
        symbol: "TST",
        uri: "https://arweave.net/v2PSXJy95LrpkcFytCLw7BCZw0lSNgoFM58VyLImExc",
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
        collection: null,
        creators: [
            {address: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(userWallet.publicKey), verified: true, share: 100}
        ],
        uses: null
    },
    isMutable: false,
    collectionDetails: null
}

// const ON_CHAIN_METADATA = {
//     name: MY_TOKEN_METADATA.name, 
//     symbol: MY_TOKEN_METADATA.symbol,
//     uri: 'TO_UPDATE_LATER',
//     sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
// } as DataV2;

/**
 * 
 * @param wallet Solana Keypair
 * @param tokenMetadata Metaplex Fungible Token Standard object 
 * @returns Arweave url for our metadata json file
 */
const uploadMetadata = async(wallet: Keypair, tokenMetadata: UploadMetadataInput):Promise<string> => {
    const metaplex = Metaplex.make(solanaConnection)
        .use(keypairIdentity(wallet));
    
    const { uri } = await metaplex.nfts().uploadMetadata(tokenMetadata);
    return uri;
}

const createNewMintTransaction = async (connection:Connection, payer:Keypair, mintKeypair: Keypair, destinationWallet: PublicKey, mintAuthority: PublicKey, freezeAuthority: PublicKey)=>{
    //Get the minimum lamport balance to create a new account and avoid rent payments
    const requiredBalance = await getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint(connection);
    const metaplex = Metaplex.make(solanaConnection);
    const umi = createUmi(connection);
    //metadata account associated with mint
    const metadataPDA = await metaplex.nfts().pdas().metadata({mint: mintKeypair.publicKey});
    const signer = {
        publicKey: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(userWallet.publicKey),
        signMessage: null,
        signTransaction: null,
        signAllTransactions: null
    }
    const accounts: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts = {
        metadata: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(metadataPDA),
        mint: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(metadataPDA), 
        payer: signer,
        mintAuthority: signer,
        updateAuthority: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(userWallet.publicKey)
    }
    //get associated token account of your wallet
    const tokenATA = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mintKeypair.publicKey, destinationWallet);
    const CreateMetadataAccountV3Args = {
        metadata: metadataPDA,
        mint: mintKeypair.publicKey,
        mintAuthority: mintAuthority,
        payer: payer,
        updateAuthority: mintAuthority,
        data: {
            name: "myname",
            symbol: "exp",
            uri: "example_uri.com",
            sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
            creators: null,
            collection: null,
            uses: null
        },
        isMutable: false,
        collectionDetails: null
    }
    const createNewTokenTransaction = new Transaction().add(
        SystemProgram.createAccount({
            fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
            newAccountPubkey: mintKeypair.publicKey,
            space: MINT_SIZE,
            lamports: requiredBalance,
            programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        }),
        createInitializeMintInstruction(
          mintKeypair.publicKey, //Mint Address
          MINT_CONFIG.numDecimals, //Number of Decimals of New mint
          mintAuthority, //Mint Authority
          freezeAuthority, //Freeze Authority
          TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID),
        createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
          payer.publicKey, //Payer 
          tokenATA, //Associated token account 
          payer.publicKey, //token owner
          mintKeypair.publicKey, //Mint
        ),
        createMintToInstruction(
          mintKeypair.publicKey, //Mint
          tokenATA, //Destination Token Account
          mintAuthority, //Authority
          MINT_CONFIG.numberTokens * Math.pow(10, MINT_CONFIG.numDecimals),//number of tokens
        ),
        createMetadataAccountV3(umi, CreateMetadataAccountV3Args)
    );

    return createNewTokenTransaction;
}

const main = async() => {
    console.log(`---STEP 1: Uploading MetaData---`);
    let metadataUri = await uploadMetadata(userWallet, MY_TOKEN_METADATA);
    //ON_CHAIN_METADATA.uri = metadataUri;

    console.log(`---STEP 2: Creating Mint Transaction---`);
    let mintKeypair = Keypair.generate();   
    console.log(`New Mint Address: `, mintKeypair.publicKey.toString());

    const newMintTransaction:Transaction = await createNewMintTransaction(
        solanaConnection,
        userWallet,
        mintKeypair,
        userWallet.publicKey,
        userWallet.publicKey,
        userWallet.publicKey
    );

    console.log(`---STEP 3: Executing Mint Transaction---`);
    const transactionId =  await solanaConnection.sendTransaction(newMintTransaction, [userWallet, mintKeypair]);
    console.log(`Transaction ID: `, transactionId);
    //console.log(`Succesfully minted ${MINT_CONFIG.numberTokens} ${ON_CHAIN_METADATA.symbol} to ${userWallet.publicKey.toString()}.`);
    console.log(`View Transaction: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${transactionId}?cluster=devnet`);
    console.log(`View Token Mint: https://explorer.solana.com/address/${mintKeypair.publicKey.toString()}?cluster=devnet`)
}


main();



The error seems to say what's wrong:
Type '{ publicKey: PublicKey; signMessage: null; signTransaction: null; signAllTransactions: null; }' is not assignable to type 'Signer'.
Types of property 'signMessage' are incompatible.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type '(message: Uint8Array) => Promise<Uint8Array>'.

the signMessage field is supposed to be a function that takes a Uint8Array and returns a Promise<Uint8Array>. If you need to mock this, you could add a function that just returns the message back without signing, ie:
const signer = {
    publicKey: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(userWallet.publicKey),
    signMessage: (msg) => Promise.resolve(msg),
    signTransaction: null,
    signAllTransactions: null
}

Note that this might still fail because of the other fields, which likely can't be null.
